# How can I template a 2D container in class?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
class X {
  //Member functions don't have template variables.
  private:
    T<T <int> > array;
};

int main() {
    X<vector> obj;
}
```

What should I write to `template<>` part to achieve that?

Comment: Are you looking for template template parameters, that is `template <template <class> class T>`?

Comment: Note that `vector` isn't a class, it's a template. `vector<int>` is a class, `vector<double>` is a class, but `vector` itself is a blueprint for making classes, not a class itself. That's the motivation behind the distinction @Quentin is making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a class template such as `std::vector` as an argument, then the template parameter needs to be a template template parameter.

```
template <template<class...> class T>
class X
{
  private:
    T<T <int> > array;
};
```

The template parameter of the template template parameter needs to be a variadic template parameter, since you are passing it `std::vector` which is templated on more than one template parameter.

Comment: It worked but i can not use it as a vector in class. I can not do array.push_back(int). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @giraffe123 It should work fine. Can you show the code that's not working? Also, note that `array.push_back(int)` is not correct, it would need to be `array.push_back(42)`, and it would need to be inside a method, not just inside the class.

Comment: using namespace std;

template <template<class ...> class T>
class X {
public:
 X();
 void add(int x);
 void print();
private:
 T<T <int> > data;
};

int main() {
 X<vector> obj;
 obj.add(5);
 obj.print();
}

template <template<class ...> class T>
void X<T>::add(int x) {
 data.push_back(x);
}

template <template<class ...> class T>
void X<T>::print() {
 cout << data[0] << endl;
}

Comment: It's very difficult to read code like that. Use an online compiler, e.g. like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/GxGnTq). The issue in your code is that `data` is `T<T<int>>` which is a `vector<vector<int>>`. You can't `push_back` an `int` to a 2D vector.

Comment: Im sorry im new. Many thanks to you i got so confused looking it over and over. it was a simple mistake. Thank you

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you got it figured out :)